# Jest check if setting is true or false

Tags: node.js, jestjs, electron

I want to make a simple jest test to check if `devTools` was left on for an Electron app. I have this function in `main.js`:

```
function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        devTools: false
    },
    frame: false
  });
```

I just want to make a test to see if devTools is false. Can jest just read that specific variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently found out about [Spectron](https://www.electronjs.org/spectron) and it allows you to test Electron apps. Their [documentation shows them using Mocha](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#usage), but I'm pretty sure you can get it working with Jest. I don't need to check if devTools is on in my Electron app anymore, but I'm posting here for anyone that wants to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the options that were passed to the [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) constructor like such:

```js
win = new BrowserWindow( {
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        devTools: true
    },
});

console.log( win.webContents.browserWindowOptions.webPreferences.devTools );
// will print true
```

Note that you can only retrieve the value if it actually appears in the constructor call options, otherwise it is `undefined`.

Further note that this is undocumented: the [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) do not mention `webContents.browserWindowOptions`. I have tried this using Electron 10.1.0.

Comment: Thank you! The console.log works, but I'm a bit confused on setting up `main.test.js`. I'm just starting out with Jest, here's my [attempt at making a main.test.js](https://gist.github.com/kyleawayan/4022ac4b10a338041eee2e4c9a7f8fae).

Comment: There are several small issues in that code. `createwindow` needs to be `createWindow` and check the `expect` syntax again, it's not quite right. Also, you're checking the return value of the function, when it doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that after I copied and pasted everything... but did you use `module.exports = createWindow()`? It gives a `Error: Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready` when I try to run the app with `npm start`.

Comment: My answer only deals with the reading of the BrowserWindow setting in Electron. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make your tests work! That seems to me to lead to a wider, more general question: how to make Jest run an Electron app with the complete UI.